# Fluent Error: received a fatal signal (segmentation fault)

Tags: fluent

I am facing this error whenever I open Fluent, I google it but most of them are facing this problem because of UDF. In my case I am not using UDF, and still getting this error. Even I cannot load fresh fluent module, as it ends up with the same errors...which are listed below

**Error: Cortex received a fatal signal (SEGMENTATION VIOLATION).**

**Error Object: ()**

**Error: eval: unassigned variable**
**Error Object: rp-seg?**

**Error: eval: unassigned variable**
**Error Object: rp-host?**

**Error: eval: unassigned variable**
**Error Object: sg-wetsteam?**